# Why does cmbStream.ValueMember = "id" display zero for all values yet cmbStream.DisplayMember = "name" display the correct value

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am following a tutorial to insert data into a combo box from the database but it seems like the ValueMember assigned is the same for all the data even though the DisplayMember is correctly displayed.

This is how I am adding the data to the ComboBox

```vb
Private Sub cmbStream_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbStream.VisibleChanged
    If cmbStream.Visible = True Then
        cmbStream.DataSource = GetStreamItems()
        cmbStream.DisplayMember = "name"
        cmbStream.ValueMember = "id"
    End If
End Sub
```

After getting the data like this

```vb
Function GetStreamItems() As List(Of StreamItem)
    Dim streamItems = New List(Of StreamItem)
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server='" & My.Settings.MServer & "';user='" & My.Settings.MDbUser & "';password='" & My.Settings.MDbPass & "';database='" & My.Settings.MDb & "'"
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT id, name FROM tbl_streams"
    Dim Command As MySqlCommand
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Command = New MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
    Command.CommandTimeout = 30
    reader = Command.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows = True Then
        While reader.Read()
            streamItems.Add(New StreamItem(reader("id"), reader("name")))
        End While
    End If
    Return streamItems
End Function
```

Here is the StreamItem class

```vb
Public Class StreamItem
    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal name As String)
        mID = id
        mName = name
    End Sub

    Private mID As Integer
    Public Property id() As Integer
        Get
            Return id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            mID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private mName As String
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return mName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mName = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

What could I be doing wrong in the code to make the ValueMember zero for all the data?

Comment: Your property get for `id` has an incorrect return variable. It shows `Return id` instead of `Return mID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the right variable for your get. It should be mID, not id.

```
Public Property id() As Integer
    Get
        Return mID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        mID = value
    End Set
End Property
```

In VB.NET, the name of the function/property is also used as some sort of variable for the return value. This is the same as doing Return 123

```
Function SomeFunc() As Integer
    SomeFunc = 123
End Function
```

Or in your case

```
Public Property id() As Integer
    Get
        id = mID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        mID = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Since you haven't set id, the default value is 0. Anyway, don't use that feature, it's confusing.

Comment: Yep. Also: set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` fields _before_ assigning the data source.